# UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency - A view can only be at most with one view controller at a time

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6

I am having a problem with updating one of my older apps, this is only since I updated to Xcode 4.5 and trying on iOS6 it gives the following error;

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'A view can only be associated with at most one view controller at a time! View <MainView: 0x1e818620; frame = (0 0; 320 476); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x1e818750>> is associated with <MainViewController: 0x1e811850>. Clear this association before associating this view with <UIViewController: 0x21149860>.'
```

*** First throw call stack:
(0x377d82a3 0x35ae897f 0x377d81c5 0x38b0dd7b 0x38b0dc6b 0x1dc25 0x38b940ad 0x38b9405f 0x38b9403d 0x38b938f3 0x38b93de9 0x38abc5f9 0x38aa9809 0x38aa9123 0x37c5c5a3 0x37c5c1d3 0x377ad173 0x377ad117 0x377abf99 0x3771eebd 0x3771ed49 0x37c5b2eb 0x38afd301 0x1bf03 0x1bea8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
[Switching to process 9219 thread 0x2403]

I think it is here that causes the issue;

```
 mailComposer = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[mailComposer setView:self];
[mailComposer setModalTransitionStyle: UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];




MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];   picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
```

As it is when I click the button which should take me to the MFMail composer that is when the app crashes out.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Edit - If I remove the first 3 lines the app does not crash out, however the mail view does not load... here are the entire code;

```
    // The actual mail window call



mailComposer = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[mailComposer setView:self];
[mailComposer setModalTransitionStyle: UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];




MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];   picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

[picker setSubject:@"Hello How are you"];

    // Fill out the email body text
NSString *pageLink = @"http://www.apple.com"; 
NSString *iTunesLink = @"http://itunes.apple.com/gb/artist/randomer";
NSString *content = @"blah blah"; 


NSString *emailFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"email_.html"];


NSString *emailFilePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent: emailFileName];
NSString *body = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:emailFilePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];


body = [body stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"//TEXT_PLACEHOLDER//" withString:@"replace here"];
body = [body stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"//FRIENDNAME_PLACEHOLDER//" withString:pageLink];
body = [body stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"//ITUNES_PLACEHOLDER//" withString:  iTunesLink];
body = [body stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"//PASSKEY_PLACEHOLDER//" withString:  yourPassword];
body = [body stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"//PHONETIC_PLACEHOLDER//" withString:  yourPhoneticPassword];




[picker setMessageBody:body isHTML:YES];    
picker.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;    
[mailComposer presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
[picker release];
```

}

```
//HANDLE THE MAIL EVENTS
////////////////////////
```

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
  { 
      // Notifies users about errors associated with the interface
  switch (result)
  {
      case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
          break;
      case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
          break;
      case MFMailComposeResultSent:
          break;
      case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
          break;

  ```
  default:
  {
      UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Email" message:@"Sending Failed - Unknown Error :-("
                                                     delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
      [alert show];
      [alert release];
  }

      break;
  ```

  }
  [mailComposer dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
      //[mailComposer.view.superview removeFromSuperview];
  }

Comment: What this line does? What's `self` here? `[mailComposer setView:self];`

Comment: you just need the last line. what are the first 3 lines for ?

Comment: Any ideas? Struggling here :(

Comment: Well, found a temporary workaround...Go back and compile in Xcode 4.2.1! And forget 4.5 until a fix is found for it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing to get the mail compose view controller to show is to present it using the currently-active UIViewController.  You didn't share enough of your code for this to be clear to me, but if `self` is a UIViewController in that context, you'd need to do:

```
[self presentViewController:picker animated: YES completion:nil];
```

If `self` isn't a UIViewController, replace `self` in the code above with a variable referencing the current UIViewController.